# Script runs fine in PyScripter, crashes in python.exe (encoding error with Beautifulsoup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pyscripter

```
def getPlural():
plural = soup.find("span", class_="form-of lang-de plural-form-of")
if plural == None:
    return None
else:
    return plural.get_text()
```

The problem seems to lie in this part of my code. Pyscripter manages to handle it fine, Python.exe returns `Error: 'charmap' codec can't encode character \xe4 in position 9: character maps to undefined.`

PyScripter and Python.exe run the same version (3.3). Why is this? How do I solve this?

Comment: play with encode() and decode(); probably you get 'bytes' and you need to convert to utf-8, so myret.decode() - default is utf-8, but you may choose something else

Answer (score 0):

you'll probably get a good run with something like this:

```
print plural.encode('utf-8')
```

or

```
print plural.prettify().encode('utf-8')
```

+*+*+*+*+**+**++**+++**+*+*+*+_*
EDITED:  Try this...

```
print plural.get_text().decode('string-escape')
```

Comment: This returns `b'Fahrr\xc3\xa4der'`where I was expecting `Fahrräder`. Again, the original code works perfectly in PyScripter, for some the error only happens when I run in python.exe.

Comment: Try this: .decode('string-escape') instead of .encode('utf-8)